# handle cases of Enums in Swift

Tags: ios, enums, swift4.2, case-statement

How can we handle the same case with different inputs from the response in `Enum`'s

```
enum MyNotificationType: String, Codable {
        case practice = "push"
        case practice = "PracticeRecommendation"
        case play = "PlayRecommendation"
        case play = "pop"
    }
```

**Edit:**

I need this because I've common *practice* `image` for

> push, PracticeRecommendation

and *play* `image` for

> PlayRecommendation, pop

**Edit 2:**

```
enum MyNotificationType: String, Codable {
    case push = "push"
    case practice = "PracticeRecommendation"
    case play = "PlayRecommendation"
    case pop  = "pop"
}
```

And added a `switch`

```
private func showImage(_ type: MyNotificationType) {
        switch type {
        case .practiceRecommendation, .push:
            self.typeImgView.image = UIImage(named: "Practice")
            break
        case .play, .pop:
            self.typeImgView.image = UIImage(named: "Play")
            break
        }
    }
```

***To deal with Images***

Comment: Could you add more context, so I can give a more proper answer? Why would you need a single case handle two different rawValues? Why can't you just declare `push` , `practiceRecommendation`, etc as a separate case?

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman I edit my question

Comment: You can't create same case in enum.

Comment: @MahendraGP thanks. I was trying to make it unique cases with different raw type.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. You can use enums with associated types, though you wouldn't be able to statically ensure possible strings unless you change init(rawType) too. Though, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so there could be a different way

```
enum MyNotificationType{
 case practice(value: String)
 case play(value: String)

 init(rawType: String){
    //define what case based on string, do error if you can't handle or use a unknown case
 }
}
```